in windows 10 and windows 11 I need to Configure a wifi profile from powershell and RCJA.xml file
I need to configure a network wifi connection with certain configuration parameters from a powershell script, and I imagine that I have to load and .xml profile with the details of the configuration, I have a powershell script and a .xml files to do it but it seems that I have problems in the format of the .xml, and I do not Know how to solutionate this question with the .xml file and the powershell script.
The wifi configuration parameters are:
name : RCJA
Type of security : AES WPA2-Enterprise
EAP method : EAP-TTLS
autentication method : non encrypted password (PAP)
the wifi must auto connect automatically when the wifi is detected, the type of encryption must be AES, the question is that the user must introduce the user account and the passwor for connectin via wifi.
# Definir las variables necesarias
$nombreRed = "RCJA"
$tipoSeguridad = "WPA2-Enterprise"
$metodoEAP = "EAP-TTLS"
$metodoAutenticacion = "PAP"

# Crear el perfil de red WiFi en XML
$xmlContent = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>$nombreRed</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>$nombreRed</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>$metodoEAP</authentication>
                <encryption>$tipoSeguridad</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <PMKCacheMode>enabled</PMKCacheMode>
            <PMKCacheSize>128</PMKCacheSize>
            <PMKCacheTTL>720</PMKCacheTTL>
            <PMKCacheVersion>1</PMKCacheVersion>
            <OneX xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/OneX/v1">
                <cacheUserData>true</cacheUserData>
                <EAPConfig>
                    <EapHostConfig xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                        <EapMethod>
                            <type>$metodoEAP</type>
                            <vendorId>0</vendorId>
                            <vendorType>0</vendorType>
                        </EapMethod>
                        <Config xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                            <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                                <Type>$metodoEAP</Type>
                                <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">
                                    <ServerValidation>
                                        <DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>
                                        <ServerNames></ServerNames>
                                    </ServerValidation>
                                    <Credentials>
                                        <Username></Username>
                                        <Password></Password>
                                    </Credentials>
                                </EapType>
                            </Eap>
                        </Config>
                    </EapHostConfig>
                </EAPConfig>
            </OneX>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
"@

# Guardar el perfil de red WiFi en un archivo XML
$xmlPath = "D:\Temporal\$nombreRed.xml"
$xmlContent | Out-File -FilePath $xmlPath -Encoding UTF8

# Eliminar el perfil si ya existe
netsh wlan delete profile name="$nombreRed"

# Agregar el perfil de red WiFi
netsh wlan add profile filename="$xmlPath"

# Establecer la red WiFi para conectar automáticamente y recordar credenciales
netsh wlan set profileparameter name="$nombreRed" connectionmode=auto
netsh wlan set profileparameter name="$nombreRed" userprofile keyUsage=persistent

# Mostrar mensaje para conectar a la red WiFi
Write-Host "Conecte a la red WiFi '$nombreRed'. Se recordarán las credenciales para esta conexión."

When I run the script I have this errors :
Errors in Spanish:
No se encuentra el perfil "RCJA" en ninguna interfaz.
Error de formato de perfil 0x80001: El perfil no es válido, de acuerdo con el esquema.
El perfil de conexión de red está dañado.
Erros in English:
The RCJA profile is not found in any interfaz
profile format error : 0x80001 : the profile is not valid, in accordance with the squeme
the network profile is damaged

I think the error is due to the schema in the XML file. "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"  Use an online xml schema checker to find error.

According to the samples found on this webpage, the URL should be using https. What happens when you change your XML to use https? Be sure to check the other URLs as well.
